# Restoring MariaDB from a mariabackup

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to copy our production database, to a staging database on the same server without locking up our production application.

Our databases on MariaDB (10.1.22-MariaDB-1~xenial) have become too large to export with mysqldump. Doing this on production locks the tables and brings our application down. I am using the new [mariabackup tool](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-backup-overview/) which is a fork of the Percona XtraBackup tool. It seemed to work fine with the following command:

```
sudo mariabackup --user=<me> --password=<something> --databases=crs_production --backup --export
```

It has left me with a crs_production directory (the name of our database) and bunch of files within it. I assume these are the same files you find in /var/lib/mysql/crs_production.

Am I safe to copy these and overwrite our staging database located at /var/lib/mysql/crs_staging? I am not super concerned with losing staging, but I am super concerned with cratering our database server in the process.

Comment: I think you should use `--prepare` to prepare a backup for starting mysql server on the backup. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariabackup-options/

Comment: Please check docs : [full-backup](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/full-backup-and-restore-with-mariadb-backup/) [incremental backup]( https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/incremental-backup-and-restore-with-mariadb-backup/)